# Installing a Python package on an environment with both 2.x and 3.x installed

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to install a mysql package compatible with Python 2.x and am having some difficulty.

If I try to install `mysql-python`, the return error message is `ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'`. From what I've found online, this seems to be tied to Python thinking trying to run Python3, and so there's some file named `configparser`.

I tried installing another package with `pip install PyMySQL` but that threw a `Permission denied error: some_directory/site-packages/pymysql` likely because I don't have `su` access. Would having an admin or someone with root access run that work?

Answer (score 0):

I had to take help from sysadmin because I couldn't run pip command.

Out machine had both python2.x and python3.x so the admin executed the following command to install module.

```
pip3 install MODULE_NAME
```